# XMLHttpRequest predefined values for LOADING, DONE, etc. become undefined under Ripple

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest, ripple

I am using XMLHttpRequest to call a REST service.

When testing is under Mozilla and Chrome everything works just fine.

Although, when I enabled the Ripple under Chrome it stopped working. After some debugging I found out that in the switch/case statement, where I do something like ...

```
switch (this.readyState) {
 case XMLHttpRequest.DONE: ... some code here ... break;
}
```

... the "case" does not get fired.

Closer examination determined that all the values XMLHttpRequest.* are *undefined* so that is the reason my code stopped working.

> Q: Why XMLHttpRequest readyState values, otherwise well defined, become *undefined* under Ripple?

Are there any solutions for that issue, other than using plain numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4 or defining the values myself.

Comment: I sounds like "Ripple" [re-]defined XMLHttpRequest when it was already present...?

Comment: Do you know this for a fact or you think this is the problem?

Comment: No, and it would be silly. However, it is the *only* explanation that I can think of to explain "all the values of XMLHttpRequest.* are undefined" (object properties don't just "magically vanish"). Well, the other is that there is a *different* `XMLHttpRequest` variable in scope. In any case 1) The properties were removed (or not added) 2) `XMLHttpRequest` resolves to a different object or 3) a combination of #1 and #2.

Comment: Perhaps the "target" Ripple is trying to emulate does *not* have those properties (so they are removed) or it uses a proxy object and does *not* add the properties (never added to proxy object)? (I have no idea how Ripple actually works under the hood, but see #1 and #2.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the Ripple Emulator 0.9.5 the testing script passes the test - the **XMLHttpRequest** values for **LOADING**, **DONE**, etc. are there.

Looks like you have to download the Ripple from https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/ripple and then manually install the Chrome extension instead of just updating the extension from the menu.

NOTE: At the time this question was asked the version above was not available so the problem existed.

NOTE2: Here is a link https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_getting_started/Use_the_Ripple_emulator_Chrome_extension_2007542_11.html with instructions how to install the extension to the Chrome, i.e. drag-and-drop the **ripple_ui.crx** file.